# Что значит это равенство?

Tags: матрицы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что значит єто равенство "ki < ki+1"? типо столбец больше чем столбец перед ним?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это означает, что первый ненулевой элемент нижней строки всегда располагается правее первого ненулевого элемента верхней строки

```
01111111
00001111
00000111
```

Answer (score 1):

столбец ki меньше чем ki+1, если выполнены условия данного равенства.

Comment: а чему равен столбец? суме єлементов в нем?